# Jquery toggle function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

HTML

```
<head>
<body id="top" class="home page page-id-1412 page-template-default logged-in stretched open_sans open_sans siteorigin-panels" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="wrap_all">
            <header id="header" class="header_color light_bg_color mobile_drop_down" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" itemscope="itemscope" role="banner">
                <div id="header_meta" class="container_wrap container_wrap_meta">
                <div id="header_main" class="container_wrap container_wrap_logo">
                <div id="header_main_alternate" class="container_wrap">
                    <div class="container">
                        <nav class="main_menu" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope" role="navigation" data-selectname="Select a page">
                           <div id="megaMenu-sticky-wrapper">
                             <div id="megaMenu" class="megaMenuContainer megaMenuHorizontal wpmega-preset-vanilla megaResponsive megaResponsiveToggle wpmega-withjs megaMenuOnClick megaFullWidth wpmega-noconflict megaMinimizeResiduals themeloc-avia megaMenu-withjs">
                                <div id="megaMenuToggle" class="megaMenuToggle">
                                <ul id="megaUber" class="megaMenu">
                                    <li id="menu-item-8" class="jrm-um-sticky-only menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home ss-nav-menu-item-0 ss-nav-menu-item-depth-0 ss-nav-menu-reg um-flyout-align-center ss-nav-menu-with-img ss-nav-menu-notext">
                                    <li id="menu-item-1459" class="my_custom_class menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children mega-with-sub ss-nav-menu-item-1 ss-nav-menu-item-depth-0 ss-nav-menu-mega ss-nav-menu-mega-fullWidth mega-colgroup mega-colgroup-6 ss-nav-menu-mega-alignCenter">
                                        <a href="#">
```

CSS

```
#overlay-2 {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
opacity: 0.85;  
z-index: 10;
display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.my_custom_class').click(function()    {
       $('#overlay-2').toggle();
    });
});
```

I want the #overlay-2 to be hidden when the page loads and then toggle show/hide when I use the menu button with a custom class assigned in wordpress nav menu "css classes" metabox. .my_custom_class is what I assigned it.

Why isn't this working?
If you could supply the corrected code that would be great :)

Thanks!

Comment: We **cannot reproduce the issue** if you don't give us the missing HTML. And what's `.my_custom_class` and why you did not added it to the HTML sample? So far this is what you gave us (+ some fixes of mine to the HTML trying to decypher your code): http://jsbin.com/EqUgUjep/1/edit

Comment: Okay HTML updated above. If there is more needed let me know. This is so frustrating! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply cause you don't have any `.my_custom_class` in your HTML

If you add a

```
<button class="my_custom_class">Toggle Overlay</button>
```

both in your document and inside the overlay you're good to go:

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/EqUgUjep/1/edit)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. As stated in the post, I added ".my_custom_class" in the "css classes" meta box in wordpress. I even tried targeting the menu item in the JS by #menu-item-number , obviously number replaced with the actual number.

Comment: I just posted the relevant html as the html of the entire page is really long

Comment: Hey @Roko C. Buljan  I updated the html in the original post. The ".my_custom_class is the second to last item"

Comment: @user3187895 sorry your HTML as it stands is unusable. Please provide a better example. Learn to use jsBin and share links to your demo examples.

Comment: @user3187895 your job is also to minify your code untill you get to the issue. posting bunch of lines fulfilled with classes makes it just  impossible to answer you easily on your answer. Usually, also, when users minify the code to spot right on their issue, they're able to fix it by them selves. So set up something readable, don't confuse us with unnecessary lines and styles. Make it simple. See my demo? simple and no issue :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I did in the beginning, or at least I thought I did. Then you wanted more and I wasn't sure what you could possibly want. Not trying to be rude here, I appreciate the help very much

Comment: @user3187895 I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, what I'd want to say is that: while posting questions you need first to present an understandable question and the *simplified needed code to reproduce the issue.* after posting your code, if you want to get an answer really accurate and fast you can additionally setup a jsBin.com example! I'd really love to help you but I repeat, it's quite hard from the provided code to spot on the issue. create a jsBin, use only the markup needed to reproduce the issue. If you don't find even than the error, post that exact example and we're here to help!